# Issue remapping keys using Scancode Map in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, regedit

I am using Acer laptop, and have attached the hardware information here:
[image: Screenshot of System Information]

The keyboard layout is as shown below:

[image: Image illustrating the keyboard layout]

I find it annoying to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> for <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Page Dn</kbd> for <kbd>End</kbd> and tried to swap the functionality to go to **<kbd>Home</kbd> on <kbd>Page Up</kbd>** and **<kbd>End</kbd> on <kbd>Page Dn</kbd>** button press by updating the registry, however, its not working.
The registry update is shown below ([reference for hex code](https://android-coffee.com/wp-content/uploads/key-code.jpg)):
[image: Screenshot of the Registry Editor showing the Scancode Map]

```
00000000     00 00 00 00     00 00 00 00  
00000000     02 00 00 00     47 00 49 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     6C 00 49 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 47 49 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 6C 49 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     47 00 7D 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     6C 00 7D 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 47 7D 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 6C 7D 00
00000000     02 00 00 00     47 00 E0 49
00000000     02 00 00 00     6C 00 E0 49
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 47 E0 49
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 6C E0 49
00000000     02 00 00 00     47 00 E0 7D
00000000     02 00 00 00     6C 00 E0 7D
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 47 E0 7D
00000000     02 00 00 00     E0 6C E0 7D
00000000     00 00 00 00
```

- please ignore the [00000000] in all the lines cause I couldn't copy the binary from the editor as such.

This is not working, I know I am missing the <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, in the binary I added above but I can replicate the same if someone can help me fix the <kbd>Page Dn</kbd> button swap.
My administrator has restricted third party software that I can install and do the remap.

Comment: You can consider using https://www.autohotkey.com/ - I already did that at an employer not allowing administrative access. You can either run the `.ahk` script with the `AutoHotkey.exe` or compile the script to a standalone `.exe`.